# Prove some sequence is a subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Given the sequence $a_n := (2+(-1)^n)\frac{n}{n+1}$, I need to find two converging subsequences. This is pretty straight forward in this case, e.g. $b_n := 3\frac{2n}{2n+1}$ and $c_n := 1\frac{2n-1}{2n}$.
The problem is now, how could I prove that the sequence $b_n$ and the sequence $c_n$ are subsequences of sequence $a_n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):b_n=a_{2n}$ and $c_n=a_{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{2n}=b_n$ and $a_{2n-1}=c_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence both sequences are respectively the subsequences of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ formed by even terms and odd terms.